# Angular trigger function for when $location is set?

Tags: angularjs

E.g. I would like to pass in a unique ID to load call the service to look up the UID of this item in my catalog. This way someone could potentially bookmark that UID for the catalog to load that item.

What i've tried is in the run function set a $rootScope variable and pass it to the controller. From my short amount of research, it doesn't [seem like a good to use $rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#-rootscope-exists-but-it-can-be-used-for-evil).

Here's a quick rewritten example of what i've done:

```
angular.run(function ($rootScope) {

   $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
        var uid = $location.search().uid;
        if(uid) {
            // Avoid setting rootScope items
            $rootScope.uid = uid;
        }

   });

})
.controller('Main', function ($scope) {
    if ($scope.uid) {
        // do stuff!
    }
});
```

Is there a way to set to trigger Angular for when a previous $location is set? The $location would then set the value for the service call.

Comment: instead of polluting `$rootScope` use service or factory

Comment: You can just put this `$on $locationChangeSuccess`  event in your controller. Or directly `$watch` over `$location.search().uid`

Comment: @pankajparkar yeah i posted that above. I'm trying to find an alternative solution than using $rootScope.

Comment: @floribon thanks. I didn't know $on event. $locationChangeSuccess, was accesibile from the controller level; because of the docs. I assumed it was only accessible from the `angular.run()` function.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking but if you would like to save some information to be used in other parts of the application such as different controllers in different views then you can use a service as follows:

```
angular.module('serviceExample', [])

.factory('UIDService', function(){
  uidService = {};

  uidService.uidDict = {};

  uidService.setUid = function(uid, value){
    uidService.uidDict[uid] = value;
  };

  uidService.getUid = function(uid){
    return uidService.uidDict[uid];
  }

  return uidService;
})

.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, UIDService){
  $scope.currentValue = 0;

  $scope.updateUidValue = function(uid){
    $scope.currentValue = UIDService.getUid(uid);
  };

  $scope.setUidValue = function(uid, value){
    UIDService.setUid(uid, value);
  };


})

.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, UIDService){
  $scope.currentValue = 0;

  $scope.updateUidValue = function(uid){
    $scope.currentValue = UIDService.getUid(uid);
  };

  $scope.setUidValue = function(uid, value){
    UIDService.setUid(uid, value);
  };
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/5JUofJ9qKmez6u1nP6yw

So if you wanted to bookmark a page you could set it in the service and then access it later from the service anywhere in your app. This would avoid using $rootScope as some global storage.

In the above example if you set the value to 5 you can update it in the controllers separately. Setting the value to 5 sets it on the service and then controllers can access the value from the service.